# Oracle APEX 5.1 connect to remote db using JDBC and query data

Tags: jdbc, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have only used db links to get access to remote db so far. Now I have to find a way to use JDBC to connect to remote db and get data. Can someone guide me what all things would I need to ask the remote db admin in order to setup a jdbc connection, and once I have the connection, how do I query the database using java stored procedure, just like I am querying it over remote db right now with db link?

Answer (score 0):

You've described a fairly complicated problem, but haven't given any information about your database or operating system. Are you connecting to a SQL Server database? MySQL? Are you running on Linux? Windows?

First, you'll need a driver. That's going to depend on the database, operating system and versions thereof that you're using. For example, here is the [Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server) (Oops, looks like it's currently unavailable.)

Second, you need to set up Oracle Heterogenous Services. That's fairly complicated and not something I can answer here. You might start with the [Database Gateway for ODBC User's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODBCU/intro.htm#ODBCU100).

Oracle does have gateways for various other databases, but they're licensed additionally from the database itself.